# Popular combobox dentro da jtable com banco de dados, como proceder?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Atualmente eu populo um combobox normal dessa maneira:

```
this.CadperfilLinha.removeAllItems();
try {
    Class.forName(Auxiliar.AcessoBanco.getDriver());
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(Auxiliar.AcessoBanco.getUrl(), Auxiliar.AcessoBanco.getUser(), Auxiliar.AcessoBanco.getPass());;
    Statement Sent = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = Sent.executeQuery("Select * from Linha");
    CadperfilLinha.addItem("Selecione...");
    while (rs.next()) {
        this.CadperfilLinha.addItem(rs.getString("LINHA"));
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

Mas agora estou precisando popular um dentro da jtable, mas não estou conseguindo. eu tenho ele montado aqui puxando apenas valores digitados dentro do código e queria que ele utilizasse do banco de dados. Alguém pode me dar uma mão?

```
String[] values = new String[]{"Ativo", "Desativado"};

TableColumn col = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2);
col.setCellEditor(new MyComboBoxEditor(values));
col.setCellRenderer(new MyComboBoxRenderer(values));

class MyComboBoxRenderer extends JComboBox implements TableCellRenderer {

    public MyComboBoxRenderer(String[] items) {
        super(items);
    }

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
            boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        if (isSelected) {
            setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
            super.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
        } else {
            setForeground(table.getForeground());
            setBackground(table.getBackground());
        }
        setSelectedItem(value);
        return this;
    }
}

class MyComboBoxEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {

    public MyComboBoxEditor(String[] items) {
        super(new JComboBox(items));
    }
}
```

Comment: Forneça um **[mcve]** para que seja possivel simular o problema e propor um solução

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se precisa popular um `JComboBox` com dados do banco e quer isolar esse preenchimento, o melhor que posso recomendar é criar um `ComboBoxModel` e fazer o preenchimento do banco no construtor dele. um ComboBoxModel nada mais é que um modelo para preencher um JComboBox, quando você cria um combo e faz `combo.addItem()`, o que ocorre na verdade é o preenchimento de um modelo interno padrão criado para o componente, esse modelo padrão é a classe [`DefaultComboBoxModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultComboBoxModel.html).

Um exemplo de como criar poderia ser conforme abaixo:

```
class MeuComboModel extends DefaultComboBoxModel {

    private ArrayList<String> itens;
    private Object itemSelected;

    public MeuComboModel() {
        this.itens = new ArrayList<>();
        this.itens.add("Option 1");
        this.itens.add("Option 2");
        this.itens.add("Option 3");
        this.itens.add("Option 4");
    }

    @Override
    public int getSize() {
        return itens.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getElementAt(int index) {
        return itens.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelectedItem(Object anItem) {
        this.itemSelected = anItem;

    }

    @Override
    public Object getSelectedItem() {
        return this.itemSelected;
    }
}
```

Criei uma classe herdando de `DefaultComboBoxModel`para que precisemos configurar o minimo possível. Nesse caso eu estou populando diretamente, mas basta atribuir os itens advindos do banco na lista no lugar.

Para atribuir o model ao combo, você pode tanto iniciar já passando uma instância dele ou definir posteriormente através do método [`setModel()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setModel-javax.swing.ComboBoxModel-):

- Método 1 :

  ```
  JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(new MeuComboModel());
  ```
- Método 2:

  ```
  seucombo.setModel(new MeuComboModel());
  ```

Até esse momento, o combo já está preenchido, e caso os itens sejam Strings ou algum tipo primitivo do java, dependendo do model que sua tabela usa, basta passar esse combo para uma instância da classe [`DefaultTableCellEditor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultCellEditor.html):

```
this.table.getColumnModel().getColumn(<<indice da coluna>>).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));
```

Com isso, o combo é exibido corretamente quando a célula dele entra em modo de edição, a opção selecionada também, como pode ser visto abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se quiser ler mais a respeito, recomendo os tutoriais oficiais da documentação: [*How to Use Tables*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) e [*How to Use Combo Boxes*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html).

Comment: Obrigado pelo exemplo @Articuno, é isso mesmo que eu estava precisando. Eu só não estou sabendo popular ele com as informações do banco de dados igual eu faço no exemplo a cima. procurei pelo youtube, pela net e não encontrei um exemplo de popular ele em si. vc poderia me ajudar com essa parte?

Comment: eu fiz de uma maneira q está errado q foi usar um combobox já existente pra puxar os itens dele com o código que vc me passou.

Comment: tem como esse combo ficar visível e caso a pessoa passe tab ou enter acione ele pra escolher uma opção?

Comment: @Lucas16 se você fornecer um [mcve] posso tentar ajudar.

Comment: problema q eu uso a tabela do próprio netbeans. pra fazer um exemplo vou demorar um pouco. mas como vc mesmo disse "Com isso, o combo é exibido corretamente quando a célula dele entra em modo de edição, a opção selecionada também, como pode ser visto abaixo:" eu gostaria q ele já aparecesse e q ao passar por ele forçar uma escolha.

Comment: @Lucas16 se você não fornecer um **[mcve]** não tem como eu te ajudar. Ficar postando resposta genérica torna ela ampla e eu posso ser negativado(e com razão) por isso.

Comment: @Lucas16 acesse o link, leia e tente aprender a criar um exemplo. Isso te ajudará não só a participar do site, mas a programar melhor, pois um **[mcve]** é uma forma de isolar muitos problemas em códigos e quase sempre ele mesmo ajuda a gente a achar os problemas.

Comment: ok, obrigado...

Comment: @Lucas16 mas a resposta respondeu a duvida da pergunta,  você sabe que pode aceitá-la ne?

Comment: pronto, acho q é isso.

Comment: @Lucas16 o netbeans possui uma aba de código. Recomendo que na medida que for mexendo na interface, dê uma olhada no que está acontecendo no código também. É importante saber fazer as mesmas coisas que o construtor grafico faz, senão você vai enfrentar esse tipo de problemas durante todo o seu desenvolvimento. Pra falar a verdade, eu nem recomendo esse construtor, ele cria código desnecessário e complicado, em um notepad é possivel fazer as mesmas coisas com muito menos linha de código e bem mais simples do que esse editor gráfico do netbeans.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71391/discussion-between-lucas16-and-articuno).

Comment: Você poderia tipar o genérico, fica mais legível

Comment: como assim? não entendi.