# Vincular Combo Box ao banco de dados Mysql - netbeans

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, netbeans

criei um banco de dados para armazenar funcionários e departamentos. no netbeans eu criei a classe funcionário e departamento com seus respectivos ID, coloquei um Frame com uma combo box para puxar todos os funcionários automaticamente e departamentos, cliquei com o botão direito na combo box e fui em vincular, coloquei o banco de dados e tal, porém, esta acontecendo que quando eu executo o programa aparece assim o valor " IDFUNC = 1",

alguém que manja poderia me auxiliar de uma forma simples como eu vinculo corretamente o combo box para pegar informações de uma tabela do banco de dados MYSQL?

OBRIGADO GALERA!!

Comment: Leia: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/204149/28595

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/105695/28595

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/267751/28595

Comment: Se ler com atenção os posts que sugeri, com certeza conseguirá fazer. Do jeito que sua pergunta está, fica dificil ajudar. não há um problema especifico, que alias pode ser resolvido de N formas. Se os links não resolverem e para que a pergunta nao seja fechada, edite-a e forneça um **[mcve]** para que possamos executar seu código e sugerir alguma solução.

Comment: Bom dia Amigo, obrigado pela ajuda, porém queria ressaltar algo que não mencionei e peço desculpas.. meu programa esta praticamente cru, apenas criei frames com com campos de cadastro e JCombobox, tive a ideia de buscar os objetos do meu banco de dados e trazer através destes combobox e estou tendo dificuldades com a ferramenta vincular objetos do netbeans. eu li os links que você me passou mas ainda fiquei confuso, tentei implementar mas não consegui..

Comment: Edmundo, se voce nao fornecer um **[mcve]**, dificilmente vai obter ajuda. Sugiro que procure ler o link e fornecer um.

Comment: Não são links edmundo, é voce ler o link que eu lhe mandei e fornecer um codigo que reproduza sua duvida e que seja executavel por qualquer um, colocar link externo do projeto inteiro nao ajuda muito, ate dificulta mais ainda. Siga minhas dicas, **leia o link**, e após ler, forneça um exemplo conforme explicado nele, clicando em **[edit]**.

Comment: eu entendi, mas como eu posso colocar o link pra você executar quando eu apenas criei a classe e fiz o jframe por orientação objeto não tem codigos.. não to sabendo te ajudar a me ajudar :(

Comment: Você leu? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Recomendo que leia, ai explica com detalhes o que precisa fazer.